# Spark Structure Streaming - add a batch column with value from currentBatchId

Tags: apache-spark, spark-streaming

Currently, we are trying to add a new column to the incoming streaming dataframe with value from `currentBatchId` of StreamExecution. This is required by our use case.

Is that possible?

Comment: Hi @Hiuming Wong, we have similar requirement. Did you find any solution?

Answer (score 2):

You can use the following UDF:

```
val batchUDF = udf { () =>
  TaskContext.get().getLocalProperty("streaming.sql.batchId").toInt
}
```

Then: `df.withColumn("batch", batchUDF())`